# Java reflection getDeclaredMethod

Tags: java, reflection

i've got this method

```
private <T> boolean send(String topic, Message protonMsg, Map<String, Object> properties, SendOptions sendOptions, CompletionListener<T> listener, T context) throws StoppedException {
```

I need to access it from another class. I tried:

```
Method indexOfMethod = NonBlockingClientImpl.class.getDeclaredMethod("send", String.class, Message.class, Map.class, SendOptions.class, CompletionListener.class, Void.class);
```

But it's not working, and it is giving me java.lang.Class.throwNoSuchMethodException. Can you please give me hints? Thanks

Comment: Why `Void.class`? `T` erases to `Object` here.

Comment: If you're not sure of parameter types: `Method method = Arrays.stream(NonBlockingClientImpl.class.getDeclaredMethods()).filter(m -> m.getName().equals("send")).filter(m -> m.getParameterCount() == 6).findFirst().get();`.